# AWS SDK - instance termination time

Tags: amazon-ec2

How do I get an instance's termination time?  I'm using the .net SDK - I can get the LaunchTime through the property by that name from a RunningInstance object. But how do I get the termination time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API does not expose this in a structured fashion, however it does record the reason for the last state transition which usually has a date: for example `User initiated (2011-06-16 13:56:08 GMT)`